# Remove zeros between a number SQL

Tags: sql

Is there a way to remove zeroes from a string using plain SQL?
I used the `trim` or `substring` function for the query.

Input:  `60400`
Output: `64`

The following SQL only removes the leading zeros from the number.

```
select amount, to_char(trim(0 from amount)) as new_amount from my_deductions;
```

Comment: MySQL or Oracle? (Don't tag products not involved - especially when they have different string handling functions...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Replace` method. Here's the documentation for [MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) and to [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm)

```
select amount, replace(amount, '0', '') as new_amount from my_deductions;
```

Comment: will this work for integer fields also  ?